# How to put AppBar just under status bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to put AppBar just under status bar, but I couldn't, what can I do?
I tried `primary:true`, or `SafeArea`, my code as below:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("ホーム"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("ホーム")),
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried code from answer, but same result.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("ホーム"),
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text("ホーム")),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: SafeArea not working?

Comment: Not working! can you show code?

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var sbHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: sbHeight),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Title"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text(sbHeight.toString())),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use more about `SafeArea` here: [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)

Comment: updated the code. Actually, On my emulator, even your code is working fine.

Comment: this is unreal, now try running this app on a physical device. All the code that I have posted here are working perfectly, tested on my emulator as well as physical device.

Comment: I want to know why, I just install flutter, VSC and Andriod Studio last week...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ptkB.png see, its working fine on my side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225036/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-mikezang).

Answer (score 0):

You should try the SafeArea. But you must wrap the entire Scaffold inside the SafeArea.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text("ホーム"),
        ),
      body: Center(child: Text("ホーム")),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Resulting Widget]

Comment: I got the same result!

Comment: Can you update your answer with the code you tried?

Comment: I tried the code and got the above result. I'm not sure what is missing out.